# Properties in parent definition are prohibited in the intellij maven on my mac osx

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have a question about my maven configuration on my MAC Intellij. I get an error that ${a-web.version} "properties in parent definition are prohibited" within parent tag in child POM.xml and that properties is defined in parent POM.xml.
But this same configuration works well on my Windows Intellij.

Below is my parent POM.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>***</groupId>
   <artifactId>a-web</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>${a-web.version}</version>
   <name>a-web project</name>
   <url>http://***</url>

   <properties>
       <a-web.version>1.0.0</a-web.version>
   </properties>

   <modules>
       <module>a-core</module>
       <module>a-web</module>
   </modules>
</project>
```

And this is my child POM.xml that configure a parent block.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>a-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>***</groupId>
        <version>${a-web.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>aweb-web</artifactId>
    <version>${a-web.version}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>aweb-web</name>
</project>
```

I've tried many methods from stackoverflow, but no one can fix it. I want to know why this Maven config have different behaviour in Mac and windows and how to fix it.

Comment: Ask yourself: How should one (Maven) get the parent without knowing the exact version?

Comment: What is the IntelliJ version in macOS and in Windows?

Comment: The child POM references the parent POM. Which version does it reference?

Comment: To use a property as version in pom as you did you have to use predefined 
 names: `${revision}`, `${sha1}` and `${changelist}` see for the details https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html Also you have to use [Maven 3.5.0](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html).

Comment: @王昭辉 Then let me be clear: While analyzing the child POM, Maven finds a reference to a parent POM with a version that is specified by a property: `${lego-web.version}`. This property is nowhere defined in the child POM. So Maven simply can't find the referenced parent.

Comment: Please show the full directory layout and from you call Maven...

Comment: Had the same error message with Intellij 2018.1.2 on Mac OS High Sierra and asked the community support on Intellij. They referred me to this link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179451

Answer (score 19):

I have run into a very similar situation when the project started using parent version properties in the commit I have just pulled. The project would not build and felt "ill-imported". An attempt to show effective pom failed with no details presented by IDEA.

As @khmarbaise pointed out in the comments[1], there are some restrictions for properties usage in maven `<parent>` declarations - the most notable is maven 3.5+ is required. The IDEA might not be using maven new enough (the bundled one in the latest IDEA I have installed was too old) so I had to switch to local install using *Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Maven Home Directory*. Once pointed to newer version, it did not start to work immediately - some of the restart/rebuild/reimport routines caused the new setting to be effective and the project to successfully import and build again.

Despite the maven version requirement was enforced in pom, it have not caused IDEA to complain the maven version it uses is old. The lack of any details that IDEA fails to inspect the project with the maven it uses did not helped either. Now when everything else works, it still says "Properties in parent definition are prohibited" in pom files.

[1] https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: yup, I see the same ... all working fine but the editor complains "Properties in parent definition are prohibited".  I guess the editor needs improving to understand this new capability of Maven, but that's all.

Answer (score 7):

Setting property `revision` in parent pom.xml and then inherit it into children, fixed the issue for me.

```
<groupId>com.java</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>Test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<modules>
    <module>backend</module>
    <module>frontend</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>
```

In the child's pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>com.java</artifactId>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
```

I use **Maven 3.6.1**

Comment: yes this is works but with this warning from maven - [WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant , the end artifact name has the correct version name

Comment: Not sure how this would find the correct parent POM version, if it needs the parent to determine the version.

Comment: check more details here https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 3):

Work for me in Idea 18.2:

1) Don't use embeded Maven. Install Maven from official site! It's help me (^_^)

2) You can try to add groupId in child pom, put `<groupId>com.iqiyi.lego.web</groupId>` before line `<artifactId>legoweb-web</artifactId>`.

Try this code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>lego-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.iqiyi.lego.web</groupId>
        <version>${lego-web.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    **<groupId>com.iqiyi.lego.web</groupId>**
    <artifactId>legoweb-web</artifactId>
    <version>${lego-web.version}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>legoweb-web</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Worked for me in IDEA 2018.3 after I switch to my own Maven (3.6.0 instead of the bundled 3.3.9

Answer (score 2):

because your maven version is lower than 3.5.2, try to use version that >=3.5.2,when the ide intellij idea bundled maven version is lower than 3.5.2,try to download zip set to use your own maven instead of the bundled one.

by the way,although maven lower than 3.5.2 show error in intellij idea,but it works ok,you can "mvn package" success.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because when you push the compiled jar  to central maven or private maven such as nexus, you can find the version in  `META-INF/maven/xxxxx/pom.xml` of sub project is

```
<version>${lego-web.version}</version>
```

not real value `<version>1.0.0</version>`.so when you want to  release a single jar, you cannot get the true version

Answer (score 1):

It is the IntelliJ IDEA bug.

At least in the IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019